# Métodos isUserAMonkey() e isUserAGoat()

Tags: android, método

Qual a real função dos métodos [`isUserAMonkey()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isUserAMonkey()) e [`isUserAGoat()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#isUserAGoat()) no  [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html?hl=pt-br)? Em que situação elas devem ser usadas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375357/proper-use-cases-for-android-usermanager-isuseragoat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O primeiro é usado para verificar se o usuário é real ou apenas um [mecanismo de testes](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html), onde pode querer ter uma ação diferente. É o que diz em uma [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7792123/221800).

Aparentemente o segundo é apenas piada ou algo que pode eventualmente ser usado com [*easter egg*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) ativo. Isso pode ser conferido em uma [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13375357/221800). Então a utilidade real é zero.

[Outras piadas](https://web.archive.org/web/20161229184345/http://www.devchronicles.com/2013/07/android-api-fun.html).

Comment: Google sendo Google. Olha isso: android.os.Handler#runWithScissors em https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/core/java/android/os/Handler.java#runWithScissors

Comment: `GRAVITY_DEATH_STAR_I`, kkkkkkkkkkkk